# Figuring out what flow the flow ID corresponds to?

Tags: case, flow

I'm getting occasional emails that my Web-to-Case is failing in a manner related to the flow with an ID of 301U0000000Cxwl. How can I determine what flow this is? Also, I haven't had any changes in the code for the Web-to-Case or any changes in Salesforce itself (at least Cases-related) in weeks, and this issue just began appearing.

Answer (score 11):

I have found instances where @lunadog's solution does not work. The most reliable way I have found is to open the Flow editor for any Flow, wait for it to load completely, then edit the URL and replace the Id of the current Flow with the Id of the Flow in question, and load the new URL.

**EDIT 1:** I just tested this, and it looks like you should be able to use this URL:
`https://<domain>/designer/designer.apexp#Id=<Flow ID>`

For example, you might use https://na2.salesforce.com/designer/designer.apexp#Id=301U0000000Cxwl to link directly to your Flow edit screen.

**EDIT 2:** After discovering this does not work in Lightning, I found an easier way:

1. Open the Developer Console.
2. Select the "Query Editor" tab and enter a query like below.

```
SELECT Id,
       FullName,
       Description
FROM Flow
WHERE Id = '301U0000000Cxwl'
```

3. Check the "Use Tooling API" box.

You will need to uncheck the box before running queries against standard or custom objects. I have found this method to be far easier than what I previously suggested.

See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/126834) for more information about retrieving Flow metadata this way.

Comment: Thanks man! helped me a lot!
You can also view how your process builder looks like in background that way!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just plug that ID into a URL for your org as long as you have access to setup and config.

For example: https://naXX.salesforce.com/301U0000000Cxwl

Comment: This doesn't works.. You won't have access privilege to the page even if you't a sys admin..

Comment: This worked nicely for me. IT took me directly to the Object that owned the Flow, and then from there i was able to check for the Flows related to that Object and fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

I have found that entering the id into a salesforce url does not work, even as a sysadmin who probably wrote most of the flows.

I have been reduced to looking at each active flow in my org, and then clicking on the active version to see the active version id in the url.  I was not able to use Workbench, Data Loader, or any other tool to look up the flow name by version ID.

Comment: this is my use case, how to get from flow version id to flow name